# Different bin sizes in a Cartesian coordinate system

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

What is the name of a Cartesian coordinate system where the X- and Y-axis have different bin sizes?, i.e. the unit in both axis do not have the same length, so the grid is formed by rectangles, not squares, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that such a system system uses coordinates with respect to an [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_basis) (but not necessarily orthonormal) basis.